# Tight upper bound of circumscribed circle radius by triangle diameter

Tags: trigonometry

Let $T$ be a triangle with diameter $d$ whose circumscribed circle has radius $r$.

What is the best constant $\alpha > 0$ for which $r \leq \alpha d$ is always true? It is obvious that $\alpha \leq 1$. Which triangle realizes this worst case upper bound?

I believe the equilateral triangle realizes the worst case but I haven't found a proof.

Comment: What is the diameter of a triangle?

Comment: The diameter of a triangle is the length of its longest side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the smallest containing circle of a triangle of diameter $d$**

Let $AB$ be the longest edge of the triangle. The third vertex, $C$, is at most $d$ from $A$ and at most $d$ from $B$. Therefore $ABC$ is enclosed in a region which differs only slightly from an equilateral triangle. This region is entirely enclosed in a circle of radius $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}d$ centred on the centroid of the underlying equilateral triangle.

The least upper bound is therefore given by $\alpha=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}d$.

Comment: This center of that smallest circle minimizes the maximum distance to the vertices of the triangle. It reminds me of the Fermat point of the triangle, which minimizes the sum of the distances.

Answer (score 1):

By taking an isosceles triangle of base $d$ and letting its height tend to $0$ one can make the radius of the circumcircle as large as you like.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is obvious and I realize that "circumscribed circle" was not the application that I had in mind originally.

Comment: Hi @shuhalo.  For info I have added a different answer for a containing circle.

Comment: Your guess was right, that's the question which I had in mind.